# resize the img i get from facebook

Tags: php, image, facebook, resize

is there a good way to get the large image and resize it / slice it so the img will not loss her quilaty and aspect ratio in php?

10x

Comment: Could you give a link to the img? Or code to embed it? Why do you want to do it in PHP? Wouldn't editing it once and then using that one a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Getting the image can be done with cURL for example. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Resizing can be done with PHPs GD img functions https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

or for better quality on resizing you can use ImageMagick or Cairo, which (at least ImageMagick definitely) require third party tools as well though. So only PHP will not be sufficient there. https://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php